# Trying to create an area table for integer multiplication

Tags: tables

I am trying to create a table like the one below. Is there a way to do this in the `tabular` environment? Or if there is a better way to do this, please let me know. Thank you in advance!

[image: Area Table Example]

MWE:

```
\begin{tabular}{c c c | c}
     & 30 & + & 7  \\\hline
    20 & 600 & & 140  \\
    + & & & \\\hline
    3 & 90 & & 21 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: what is the role of plus signs? anyway, do you have a MWE?

Comment: The plus signs are there because the students are trying to calculate 37*23 using this table. What is a MWE?

Comment: He means, show us what you have tried so far, and what you are finding hard. See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: ```\begin{tabular}{c c c | c}
     & 30 & + & 7  \\\hline
    20 & 600 & & 140  \\
    + & & & \\\hline
    3 & 90 & & 21 \\\hline
\end{tabular}```

Comment: I updated the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must confess I don't understand the meaning of the `+` symbols in a table devoted to multiplication operations. I therefore omit them from the following solution.

The solution provides two LaTeX macros. The main macro is called `\mytab`, and it takes four arguments: the two integers in the top row of the `tabular` environment, and the two integers in the left-hand column. There's also an auxiliary macro called `\mply` (short for "multiply", I suppose) that performs the multiplication operations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\mply[2]{\the\numexpr#1*#2}
\newcommand\mytab[4]{%
\begingroup
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt} % default: 6pt
    \begin{tabular}{| r | r  r|}
    \cline{2-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & #1 & #2  \\
    \hline
    #3 & \mply{#1}{#3} & \mply{#2}{#3}  \\
    #4 & \mply{#1}{#4} & \mply{#2}{#4}  \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\mytab{30}{7}{20}{3}

\medskip
\mytab{10}{40}{8}{15}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I agree, I think I am going to omit the plus signs as well since it is a straight multiplication table. Much appreciated.

Comment: Why not `\the\numexpr#1*#3` instead of `\mply{#1}{#3}`? Or `xint` if the argument is that the numbers may become too large.Then this would also work with pdflatex and xelatex.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat - An excellent suggestion! :-) I've updated my answer to make  `\mply` execute `\the\numexpr#1*#2`. (Aside: I'm maybe too familiar with the ways things can be done in LuaLaTeX...)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an MWE. I have defines three `\parbox` macros with different height and width to fill the cells and align its contents. The `multicolumn`s are for removing line from some of the cells:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\newcommand{\pbi}[1]{\parbox[c][0.55cm][c]{1.1cm}{\centering #1}}
\newcommand{\pbii}[1]{\parbox[c][1.1cm][c]{1.1cm}{\centering \textcolor{red}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\pbiii}[1]{\parbox[c][1.1cm][c]{0.55cm}{\centering #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \pbi{30 \hfill  $+$ } & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\pbi{7}}  \\
\cline{2-3}
\pbiii{20 $+$ }&\pbii{600}&  \pbii{140} \\
\hline
\pbiii{3} & \pbii{90} & \pbii{21} \\
\cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I like this approach.

Comment: @BuddyKingsGalletti If you remove the plus signs and hte \hfill, the other number will be centred.

Comment: Perfect, thanks again!