# Multiplying two numbers in TeX after expanding their definitions

Tags: macros

I want to automatically compute the total number of points in an assignment (each problem is worth 4 points). If I mark the last problem with `\label{last}`, I can determine the number of problems using `\ref*{last}` from the `hyperref` package. I [stole](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/525141/18170) a macro `\mply` that is supposed to multiply two numbers. However, it seems that `\ref*{last}` doesn't get fully expanded to its value and I get an error. I tried using `\edef` but to no avail. Below is a minimal example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}

\newcommand{\mply}[2]{\the\numexpr#1*#2}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Number of problems: \ref*{last} \\
Number of points: \mply{4}{\ref*{last}}

\begin{problem}
Prove this.
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}\label{last}
Prove that.
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: \ref is protected, so you can't use it for anything except priint.  You need \getrefnumber from the refcount or hyperref packages.

Comment: Yep, that solved the problem!